# AngularJS: Commit/Rollback model based on $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ngresource

I'm trying to find a generic solution to commit/rollback a model alongside ng-resource.

**When to commit/save model:**

1. Successful http write methods (PUT, POST, PATCH).

**When to rollback/reset model:**

1. Failing http write methods.
2. User deciding to cancel their local changes (before PUT).

I've found pieces of this solution scattered, but no comprehensive strategy.

My initial strategy was to make use of the default ng-resource cache. Controller starts with GETting an item. If a subsequent PUT/POST/PATCH failed (caught either in the controller's promise, or in the $resource.<write_method>'s `interceptor.responseError`, re-run the GET that first got the object, and replace my model with that, as on initial load. However, this doesn't help if there's a successful PUT, followed by a failed one, because I'd be replacing my model with a stale object. The same problem occurs when a user tries to cancel their form changes before submitting... the last successful GET may be stale.

I've got a model with ~10 properties, and multiple <form>s (for html/design's sake) that all interact with this one object that gets PUT upon any of the forms being submitted:

```
{'location_id': 1234,
 'address': {
   'line1': '123 Fake St'}
    ...
 },
 'phone': '707-123-4567',
 ...
}
```

Models already have nice rollback features, but getting ng-resource to touch them seems tricky, and I really want to reset the entire object/model. Using a custom cache alongside my $resource instance seems like a decent way to go, but is equally tricky to give user-interaction a way to rollback. Another idea was to store a separate object when loading into scope: `$scope.location = respData; $scope._location = angular.copy(respData);` that I could load from when wanting to roll back, by way of `$scope.location = $scope._location;`, but I really don't want to clutter my controllers site-wide with these shadow objects/functions (DRY).